# Webview (height=0/weight=1) doesn't relayout after neighbor GONE/VISIBLE

Tags: java, android, layout

I have a layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/map_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/skip_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/button_height"
        android:text="@string/skip"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

My code hides skip_button (via `.setVisibility(View.GONE)`) when user pick its coordinates in `map_view` webview. Also user has an ability to reset its coordinates and then button must appear again.

It works on Android 5, but on Android 4 button stay hidden even after `.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)`. I tried:

1. `mapСontainer.getParent().requestLayout();`
2. `mapСontainer.refreshDrawableState();`
3. `skipButton.refreshDrawableState();`
4. Wrap webview into `LinearLayout`

But all this doesn't help.

Comment: visibility doesn't seem to hv issue. I suspect the issue is cuz of ur layout structure. remove layout **layout_weight** and use normally **match_parent** in webview. move ur button above webview. let's see you still hv this.

Comment: I can't move button above webview. I'm using Yandex maps js api in webview and they have logo and "Terms of use" at the bottom of page. It is illegal to cover or hide this link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beat this. It looks like this is a api16 bug so i have to workaround it...

```
if (dataOk) {
    skipButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) mapСontainer.getLayoutParams();
    layoutParams.height = 0;
    layoutParams.weight = 1;
    mapСontainer.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    mapСontainer.getParent().requestLayout();
} else {
    int visibility = skipButton.getVisibility();
    skipButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    if (visibility == View.GONE) {
        int height = mapСontainer.getMeasuredHeight();
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams skipParams = skipButton.getLayoutParams();
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams containerParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) mapСontainer.getLayoutParams();
        containerParams.height = height - skipParams.height;
        containerParams.weight = 0;
        mapСontainer.setLayoutParams(containerParams);
    }
}
```